# Error accessing query parameter with useRouter in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm facing an issue while trying to access query parameters in Next.js 13 using the useRouter hook. When I run the following code

```
'use client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';


const Post = () => {
    const router = useRouter();  
    
    return (
        <div>
            post number : {router.query.id}
        </div>

  )
}

export default Post
```

I receive the following error:

**Unhandled Runtime Error**

TypeError: router.query is undefined

*Source*

```
  25 |   return (
  26 |       <div>
> 27 |           post number : {router.query.id}
     |                         ^
  28 |       </div>
  29 | 
  30 | )
```

i take the code from the official website *Routing:Dynamic Routes*,

you can look [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)

i log it in the console to see what inside the variable router, i get this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWeMn.png)

Comment: is your filename setup correctly?

Comment: @ChrisLi i think so, i have a folder named `[id]` and inside it there is the index page name `page.tsx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### i got the answer that it worked for me (getting URL params)

I encountered the issue while trying to access query parameters using the `useRouter` hook from `next/router` inside the app directory in Next.js. After referring to the Next.js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted)

> This can also happen when you try to use the useRouter hook from next/router inside the app directory, as the App Router's useRouter from next/navigation has different behavior to the useRouter hook in pages.

To resolve this issue, you can make use of the `useParams` hook from the `next/navigation` package. This hook provides a solution for **getting URL params** , without relying on useRouter.

Here's an example of the modified code that successfully access query parameters:

```
'use client'
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';

const Post = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      Post number: {id}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

By using `useParams`, you can directly destructure the `id` parameter from the route and utilize it within your component.

Keep in mind that the example code assumes you are using the latest version of Next.js (v13.4.6).

Comment: The question is regarding dynamic query params and not static url params. This approach would require creating an additional [id] route.

Comment: Didn't work with me

Comment: @MohamedSaleh i can't help if you just i doesn't work with you, you can give us more details to see what is the problem

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because the router.query object is not ready yet when the component first renders. This is because Next.js pre-renders pages on the server, and the query parameters are not available at that time.

To fix this, you can use the useEffect hook to wait until the router is ready before accessing the query parameters.

See the below code:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      const id = router.query.id;

      // write whatever you want

    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  return (
    <div>
      Post number: {router.query.id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

After fixing that, your code should work.I am giving the docs reference here:

> isReady: boolean - Whether the router fields are updated client-side
> and ready for use. Should only be used inside of useEffect methods and
> not for conditionally rendering on the server.
> https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-object

Comment: i did this before but it gave me an error like this 

`Failed to compile

./src/app/posts/[id]/page.tsx
ReactServerComponentsError:

You have a Server Component that imports next/router. Use next/navigation instead.
`

they say i have to use `next/navigation` instead of `next/router`
i used the `next/navigation` and it gave the error in the main quesion

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if it is working not!!

Comment: @LifaMohammedSeddik If it helped you, please accept the answer as correct answer and give an upvote. It will inspire me.

Comment: @SayedMohammedYassir it does not work, it gave anther error,
According to what they said in their[docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted)
i think the App directory cause this issue.   This can also happen when you try 
to use the useRouter hook from next / router inside the app directory, as the App Router's useRouter from next/navigation has different behavior to the useRouter hook in pages